# Calculating relative molecular mass given mass of solute and solvent, as well as freezing point depression, but no cryoscopic constant?

Tags: phase

Find RMM of anthracene given that when 0.813g is dissolved in 45g of benzene. freezing point of depression is 0.51 degrees celsius.